# Count Tasks By Department - Laravel Query Builder

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm new on this subject,

I have one table called Users and that has a column called department_id

I have another table called tasks and it has a column called user_id and completed_at

I would like to know how many tasks were completed by each department

please help me to do it in laravel

```php
foreach($departments as $department){

            $tasks = DB::table('tasks')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=' , 'tasks.user_id')
            ->join('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'users.department_id')
            ->where([
                ['departments.id', '=', $department->id],
                ['tasks.completed_at', '!=', null]
            ])
            ->select('tasks.id as task')
            ->get();

        }
```

Comment: Don't know the exact Laravel syntax for this query builder but what you might need (conceptually) in this particular case (already being inside the "departments loop"), is to grab the count(*). In other words, the select should be something like select('count(\*) as totalTasksCompleted').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `count()` simple way close to your code:

```
foreach($departments as $department){
    $tasks = DB::table('tasks')
    ->join('users', 'users.id', '=' , 'tasks.user_id')
    ->where('users.department_id', $department->id),
    ->where('tasks.completed_at', '!=', null)
    ->count();
    // echo "$department->id : $tasks";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select raw a count like this

```
...
->select(DB::raw('count(tasks.id) as task_count'))
...
```

Don't forget that count is a non aggregate function so you can disable it in your database variables OR add at the end a groupBy method

```
...
->groupBy('departments.id')
```

This is my version of your code:

```
$departments = DB::table('tasks')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=' , 'tasks.user_id')
            ->join('departments', 'departments.id', '=', 'users.department_id')
            ->where([
                ['departments.id', '=', $department->id],
                ['tasks.completed_at', '!=', null]
            ])
            ->select('departments.id')
            ->select(DB::raw('count(tasks.id) as task_count'))
            ->groupBy('departments.id')
            ->get();

foreach($departments as $department) {
    //$department->task_count
    //$department->id
}
```

Don't Forget to add the DB Facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
```

OR if your eloquent is properly configured you can use it instead of the query builder above:

```
//$user = User::find(1);

foreach($user->departments as $department) {
    $task_count = $department
        ->tasks
        ->map(fn($task) $task->completed_at != null)
        ->count();
}
```